# cuckoo Error "IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error"

Tags: ubuntu, cuckoo

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/bin/vmcloak", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(main())`
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in **call**
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1060, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmcloak/main.py", line 251, in init
if not h.buildiso(mount, iso_path, bootstrap, tempdir):
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmcloak/abstract.py", line 250, in buildiso
copytreelower(mount, outdir)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cuckoo-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmcloak/misc.py", line 53, in copytreelower
os.path.join(dstdir, path.lower()))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 98, in copyfile
copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 63, in copyfileobj
buf = fsrc.read(length)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error`